# Show only 2-vowel words from word list; only getting the first one

Tags: python

```
def vowels(list):
    res = []
    for word in list:
        vowel_n = 0
        for x in word:
            if x in 'aeiou':
                vowel_n+=1
                
                if vowel_n== 2:
                    res.append(word)
                    return res

print(vowels(['tragedy', 'proof', 'dog', 'bug', 'blastoderm']))
```

> Result: ['tragedy']

I'm expecting to show all characters that only have 2 vowels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reducing the indentation of the `if vowel_n== 2:` block by 2 levels (needs to be the same level with the inner loop). Currently, it's not checking the vowel counter unless the letter is a vowel.

And move `return` to outside of the loop. You're returning the result after the first word that matches the condition.

Check out this repl.it project: https://replit.com/@HarunYilmaz1/PrudentPalegreenScans#main.py

```
def vowels(word_list):
    res = []
    for word in word_list:
        vowel_n = 0
        for x in word:
            if x in 'aeiou':
                vowel_n+=1
                
        if vowel_n== 2:
            res.append(word)

    return res
```

Comment: This **does not work**. The returned list contains 'blastoderm' which has 3 vowels and yet, surprisingly, is accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: @Cobra I think you're right. OP need the words **that only have 2 vowels**. I'll update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a good idea to normalise the words to lowercase and work on that. Also, don't use built-in function names as variables:

```
VSET = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}

def vowels(lst):
    res = []
    for word in map(str.lower, lst):
        if sum(c in VSET for c in word) == 2:
            res.append(word)
    return res

print(vowels(['tragedy', 'proof', 'dog', 'bug', 'blastoderm']))
```

**Output:**

```
['tragedy', 'proof']
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution heavily relies on list comprehensions.

*"List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists."* [[Python Documentation]](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

`[letter for letter in word if letter in "aeiou"]` iterates over the letters of a word (`str` is iterable) and creates a list made only of vowels.

By applying `len()` to this list we get the number of vowels in the word.

As we want to keep only the words which have 2 vowels, we iterate over the words and to do that we also use a list-comprehension : `[word for word in words]`.

The "letter" list-comprehensions is nested in the "word" list-comprehension.

```py
words = ['tragedy', 'proof', 'dog', 'bug', 'blastoderm']
print([word for word in words if len([letter for letter in word if letter in "aeiou"]) == 2])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.